# Effective nested summation

Tags: function-construction

My problem is the following: given a list of probabilities $p_0, p_1, \dots, p_M$ and an integer $n$, I need to compute a function of a real variable $x$

$$W(x) = \sum_{m_1 = 0}^M \sum_{m_2 = 0}^M \dots \sum_{m_n = 0}^M \left( \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{ p_{m_j}}{ m_j !}\right) \frac{ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\right)! }{ ( - n)^{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i} } L_{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i } (x),
$$
where $L_i (x)$ is the Laguerre polynomial `LaguerreL[i,x]`.

My current (inefficient) solution is this:

```
w[x_, n_, probs_] :=   (* probs = {p0, p1, p2, .., pM} *)
Module[ {mM = Length@probs -1 , mj },
    With[
    { sumIt = Sequence@@Table[ { mj[i], 0 , mM}, {i, 1, n}]},
    Sum[
    Module[ { sumMJ = Sum[ mj[j], {j,1, n}]},
    Product[ probs[[ mj[j]+1]]/ ((mj[j])!), { j , 1, n}]
    sumMJ! ( -1)^sumMJ / n^sumMJ LaguerreL[ sumMJ , x ]], 
    sumIt]
]]
```

It takes quite a long time to compute, e.g. with $n=9$ and $M = 3$ it returns the result after about 2 minutes.  I guess this is because the approach is quite procedural.  I would like to derive this function for the values $n \leq 40$ and $M \leq 5$, which I am afraid would take a few weeks.

Therefore, my question is, is it possible to compute this function more efficiently in Mathematica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**2nd Update:**  I've added the rationale I used to obtain the more compact sum.

**Update:**  This is now (hopefully) an answer.  At end of the case where $M=1$ is the general case.

**Original "answer":**

This is an extended comment.  By setting $M$ to some value and then looking for a pattern for various values of $n$, one might find a quicker formula.

For example, consider $M=1$.  Looking at the coefficients for a few values of $n$ and using `FindSequenceFunction`, I get the following:

```
c[n_] := DifferenceRoot[
  Function[{y, i}, {(-(n + 1) + i) y[i] + n y[1 + i] == 0,  y[1] == 1}]][#] & /@ Range[n + 1]

w2[x_, n_] := Table[p[0]^(n - i) (-1)^i p[1]^i LaguerreL[i, x], {i, 0, n}] . c[n]

AbsoluteTiming[w2[x, 15];]
(* {0.013407, Null} *)
AbsoluteTiming[w[x, 15, {p[0], p[1]}];]
(* {8.23932, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[w2[x, 40];]
(* {0.0418239, Null} *)
AbsoluteTiming[w[x, 40, {p[1], p[2]}];]
(* Still waiting after several minutes *)
```

**General case:**

```
w3[x_, n_, m_] := Module[{t, r},
  t = Flatten[Permutations[#] & /@ (PadRight[#, m + 1] & /@IntegerPartitions[n, m + 1]), 1];
  r = Range[0, m];
  c1 = (n!/Times @@ (#!)) (1/Times @@ (r!^#)) (r . #)!/(-n)^(r . #) & /@ t;
  c2 = Product[p[i]^#[[i + 1]], {i, 0, m}] & /@ t;
  c3 = LaguerreL[r . #, x] & /@ t;
  Total[c1 c2 c3]
  ]

AbsoluteTiming[w[x, 3, {p[0], p[1], p[2]}]]
```

[image: Result with OPs code n=3 and M=2]

```
AbsoluteTiming[w3[x, 3, 2]]
```

[image: Faster code]

Check on if the results are the same:

```
w[x, 3, {p[0], p[1], p[2]}] - w3[x, 3, 2]
(* 0 *)
```

A more lengthy calculation:

```
AbsoluteTiming[w3[x, 40, 4];]
(* {251.448, Null} *)
```

**Rationale for the more compact summation:**

We have the following sum:

$$W(x) = \sum_{m_1 = 0}^M \sum_{m_2 = 0}^M \dots \sum_{m_n = 0}^M \left( \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{ p_{m_j}}{ m_j !}\right) \frac{ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\right)! }{ ( - n)^{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i} } L_{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i } (x)$$

Because we can write

$$\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{ p_{m_j}}{ m_j !}=\prod_{i=0}^M p_i^{k_i}/\prod_{j=1}^n  m_j !$$

where $\sum_{i=0}^M k_i=n$, for each combination of the $m_i$ indices the $n(M+1)$ terms are of the form

$$\left(\prod_{i=0}^M p_i^{k_i}/\prod_{j=1}^n  m_j ! \right) \frac{ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\right)! }{ ( - n)^{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i} } L_{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i } (x)$$

For example, suppose $M=2$, $n=5$, $m_1=0$, $m_2=1$, $m_3=1$, $m_4=2$, and $m_5=1$.  The associated term is

$$\left(\prod_{i=0}^M p_i^{k_i}/\prod_{j=1}^n  m_j ! \right) \frac{ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\right)! }{ ( - n)^{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i} } L_{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i } (x)=p_0 p_1^3 p_2 \frac{5!}{0! (1!)^3 2! (-5)^5}L_5 (x)$$

which simplifies to

$$-\frac{12}{625}p_0 p_1^3 p_2 L_5 (x)$$

There are 19 other combinations of the $m_i$ values that result in the same exact term.  How to calculate that multiplier?  Of the 5 values of $m_i$ there is one 0, three 1's, and one 2.  So 1, 3, and 1 are the powers of $p_0$, $p_1$, and $p_2$, respectively.  The desired count is given by

$$\frac{5}{1!3!1!}=20$$

The coefficient associated with $p_0 p_1^3 p_2 L_5 (x)$ is then

$$20*(-\frac{12}{625})=-\frac{48}{125}$$

So (again, for this example) we just need to generate all of the combinations of $p_0^{k_0} p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2}$ where $k_i \geq 0$ and $k_0+k_1+k_2=n$, construct the associated term, and then multiply by the number of combinations of the $m_i$ that will generate that term (which is $\frac{n!}{k_0!k_1!k_2!}$).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very impressive. I would absolutely love to learn more about the way you were able to come up with this solution.